# Change perspective on image with canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I need to change perspective on three images on a canvas with html5 javascript. I want three images to lean towards the screen. Here's my code, so far;

```
 function loadImages(sources, callback) {
    var images = {};
    var loadedImages = 0;
    var numImages = 0;
    // get num of sources
    for(var src in sources) {
      numImages++;
    }
    for(var src in sources) {
      images[src] = new Image();
      images[src].onload = function() {
        if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
          callback(images);
        }
      };
      images[src].src = sources[src];
    }
  }
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var sources = {
    front: 'img/slide1.png',
    lefty: 'img/slide2.png',
    righty: 'img/slide3.png',
    slideLogo: 'img/slideLogo.png'
  };

  loadImages(sources, function(images) {
    context.drawImage(images.righty, 610, 55, 300, 250);
    context.drawImage(images.lefty, 50, 55, 300, 250);
    context.drawImage(images.front, 305, 100, 350, 300);
    context.drawImage(images.slideLogo, 130, 300, 700, 206);
  });
```

The images I want to lean is front, lefty and righty.

Thanks!

Comment: make a jsfiddle for us :)

Comment: Is it 3 'constant' images ? because the canvas is meant for 2D, and even if setTransform allows to skew an image it is not convincing. So either pre-process the images, or you have to go for a pixel-by-pixel hand-processing of the image (with getImageData), which would be slow which doesn't matter since it's only at load time.

Comment: Tip: See affine or quadrilateral transformations (or even "Mode 7" in this case :-) ).